# Group values in Pandas DataFrame based on calculations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521967/pandas-dataframe-matrix-based-calculation). Any way I have provided all the details in this question also.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,0,1],[2,1,1,0,1],[3,1,1,1,1],[4,0,1,0,1]])
df.columns = ['session','p1','p2','p3','p4']
df1 = df.set_index('session')
common = df1.dot(df1.T)
print common / np.sqrt(np.outer(*[df1.sum(1)] * 2))

session         1         2         3         4
session                                        
1        1.000000  1.000000  0.866025  0.816497
2        1.000000  1.000000  0.866025  0.816497
3        0.866025  0.866025  1.000000  0.707107
4        0.816497  0.816497  0.707107  1.000000
```

Now I need to get the upper triangular part of the matrix.

```
print np.triu(common / np.sqrt(np.outer(*[df1.sum(1)] * 2)))
```

output:

```
[[ 1.          1.          0.8660254   0.81649658]
 [ 0.          1.          0.8660254   0.81649658]
 [ 0.          0.          1.          0.70710678]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          1.        ]]
```

I don't need the values in the diagonal and from the rest of the values in the upper side need to group sessions who are having the same values. For example in the previous case session groups are like following.

```
session 1,3 and 2,3
session 1,4 and 2,4
session 3,4
session 1,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
res = common / np.sqrt(np.outer(*[df1.sum(1)] * 2))
import itertools
for col in res.columns:
    for _,g in res.groupby(col):
        pairs = zip(list(g.index[g.index < col]),itertools.repeat(col))
        if pairs: print pairs
```